# Using HTML5 canvas / CSS to make an actual size printout

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

I'm making a web page designed to be printed out so the user can cut out a template of a specific physical size, essentially a 9 inch x 3.25 inch rectangle. I'm using HTML5 canvas to draw my design. I specified the size of the canvas element as `9in` by `3.25in` in my CSS, but the print preview seems to vary depending on the page orientation.

How can I ensure that, when printed on any printer, in any orientation, the rectangle is *exactly* 9 x 3.25 inches on paper?

CSS:

```
canvas#c1 {
    width:9in;
    height:3.25in;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="c1" width="900" height="325" ></canvas>
```